# Loop over a map and skip empty items

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

## **What I want**

In terraform, I have a map `service_map`:

```
variable "service_map" {
  type        = map
  description = "Map of some services and their ports."
  default     = {
    "dns"    = "53"
    "web"    = "443"
    "ssh"    = "22"
    "proxy"  = ""
  }
}
```

To create LB listeners on AWS, I want to call the resource `aws_lb_listener`, looping over the map `service_map`, **skipping all items without value** (in this case, only `proxy`):

```
resource "aws_lb_listener" "listeners" {
  for_each          = var.service_map
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.all_lbs[each.key].arn
  port              = each.value
  protocol          = each.key != "dns" ? "TCP" : "TCP_UDP"
  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.service_map-tg[each.key].arn
  }
}
```

## What I tried

1. Create a second, local map with all key=value pairs where value is not empty:

```
locals {
  service_map_temp = [ for service, port in var.service_map : service, port if port != "" ]
}
```

Which does not work: `Extra characters after the end of the 'for' expression.`. And I guess there are smarter solutions than that approach.

2. Idea: Skipping empty `each.value`s:

```
resource "aws_lb_listener" "listeners" {
  for_each          = var.service_map
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.all_lbs[each.key].arn
  port              = each.value != "" # Skipping part
  protocol          = each.key != "dns" ? "TCP" : "TCP_UDP"
  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.service_map-tg[each.key].arn
  }
}
```

But I doubt that's going to work because I am still calling the resource but with an empty port, which will fail. Since I am just starting out with terraform, I am sure there is a solution I did not think/read about yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your first solution failed because you have used list brackets `[ ... ]` but you intend to produce a map. To produce a map from a `for` expression, use map brackets `{ ... }`:

```
locals {
  service_map_temp = {
    for service, port in var.service_map :
    service => port if port != ""
  }
}
```

The key difference is that a map `for` expression expects two expressions after the colon (the key and the value), while the list `for` expression expects only one.

If you like, you can inline that expression directly in the `for_each` argument, to keep everything together in one block:

```
resource "aws_lb_listener" "listeners" {
  for_each = {
    for service, port in var.service_map :
    service => port if port != ""
  }

  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.all_lbs[each.key].arn
  port              = each.value
  protocol          = each.key != "dns" ? "TCP" : "TCP_UDP"

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.service_map-tg[each.key].arn
  }
}
```

Comment: Syntax is not quite correct, it has to be `=>` to create a map:  `for_each = { for service, port in var.service_map : service => port if port != "" }`

Answer (score 3):

I realized that if you set the parameter to `null` instead of an empty string `""`, it will automatically remove the key from the map without having to create a for loop.

```
variable "service_map" {
  type        = map
  description = "Map of some services and their ports."
  default = {
    "dns"   = "53"
    "web"   = "443"
    "ssh"   = "22"
    "proxy" = null
  }
}

output "service_map" {
  value = var.service_map
}
```

```
$ terraform apply

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

service_map = {
  "dns" = "53"
  "ssh" = "22"
  "web" = "443"
}
```

Comment: That's a helpful addition, because once can avoid having to create a `locals` block.